# JS: Nested for loop while parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, loops, for-loop

```
for (kind in animals) {
  content += animals[kind][0].name + '<br>';
}
```

This returns the first name of each animal kind from my JSON. I'm struggling to get ALL names rather than just `[0]`. Since there doesn't appear to be a simple wildcard like `[*]`, I tried putting a second for loop inside the first one like so:

```
for (var kind in animals) {
  for (var i in kind) {
    content += animals[kind][i].name + '<br>';
  }
}
```

But as it should, that simply doesn't work.

I know this is easily accomplished with something like Underscore.JS but I would really like to do it with just pure vanilla.

Comment: Your 2 lines assume that `kind` is two different things.

Comment: Have you tried structuring your second for loop to look like this: for(var i in animals.kind){}?

Comment: Whats your JSON structure look like? The first example makes it look mile a 2-d array, the second makes it look like and array of objects.

Comment: `kind` is a **key** (property name). But you use it as object which is wrong

Comment: Basically, here's a stripped version. {"cat": [ {"name": "Wilbur"}, {"name": "Stella"} ], "horse": [ {"name": "Bob"}, {"name": "Jesse"} ] }

Comment: @Robert I tried doing that but it didn't seem to work. That was  great idea though.

Comment: @Barry I think I actually misread your question - I think a standard for loop should work for you - try looping through kind like you would with a normal array, not an object and that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU `animals[kind]` is an array.
In this case you can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of nested loop (which is wrong in your code).

```
for (var kind in animals) {
  animals[kind].forEach(function(v) {
    content += v.name + '<br>';
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to the name in the `content +=` line, you correctly use `animals[kind]`, but you also need to specify that as the thing to be looped over. `kind` is just the property, what you want to loop over is the array held by `animals[kind]`:

```
for (var kind in animals) {
  for (var i in animals[kind]) {
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    content += animals[kind][i].name + '<br>';
  }
}
```

It's considered bad practice to use `for...in` to loop over arrays, for for the purposes of this question, that's not the important thing.